# Hybris create promotion For every X items bought, Save 99% Off on the lowest price item

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, promotions

I'm struggling to figure out how can I create a promotion type: "For every 3 items bought, Save 99% Off on the lowest price item" with the new promotions system of hybris from Backoffice, it's not very intuitive. Which are the conditions and actions that I must set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **Conditions**, you will need to create a **container** with the products that qualify. (Container, with nested **qualifying products** condition or **qualifying categories**)

In the **actions** part, you need to use the **partner-product** promotion type. Here you can specify the discount value, the selection strategy => cheapest. In this configuration, you need to define the qualifying container and container to receive the discount. In your case both need to be the same container. With these containers, you can specify how many products are needed (qualifying product containers) and how many get discounted (target product containers)

This should look something similar to this, with your products added.
[image]

You can find more info on this promotion type on the [SAP help](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/1811/en-US/965b07cbf84e4e0b9d9dbdcba25e7be6.html)

Comment: Very well explained with all the details needed in order to understand it. Thanks Yoni!